# Convert function names to snake case with clang-tidy

Tags: c, clang-tidy, snakecasing

I have a bunch of C code whose function names are in CamelCase and I have to convert them all to snake_case.

I found that there is a tool call `clang-tidy` that seems to be able to do this but I can't make sense of the documentation, there are a lot of options and I am afraid to shoot myself in the foot.

Would you be kind enough to provide me with a one liner ?

Comment: Are you using version control?  If not, you should be.  Then there is no risk of shooting yourself in the foot - worst case scenario you just revert your changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the one liner just to rename functions :

```
clang-tidy \
    --fix \
    --checks='-*,readability-identifier-naming' \
    --config="{
        CheckOptions: [
            {key: readability-identifier-naming.FunctionCase, value: lower_case},
        ],
    }" \
    yourfile.c -- -std=c17
```

The purpose of `--fix` is to apply changes, else you will just have a bunch of warnings.

Config is YAML. You can dump the config into a `.clang-tidy` file and clang tidy will use that.

There are other options for renaming variables, structs... You name it :
https://sarcasm.github.io/notes/dev/clang-tidy.html#identifier-naming